# Rspec Expect Child Method Invocation Without Causing Parent Method To Fail

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I would like to be able to simply test that a method is being called inside another method, without testing anything else.

Let's assume I have a method that makes an internal service call.

```
class Foo
  def self.perform
    result = InternalService.call
    ...
    result.attribute_method # do stuff with result
  end
end
```

`InternalService` has all of its own unit tests, and I don't want to duplicate those tests here. However, I still need to test that `InternalService` is being called.

If I use Rspec's `expect` syntax, it will mock out `InternalService.call` and the rest of the method will fail because there will be no result.

```
allow_any_instance_of(InternalService).to receive(:call).and_return(result)
Foo.perform

=>  NoMethodError:
=>   undefined method `attribute_method'
```

If I use RSpec's `allow` syntax to explicitly return a result, the `expect` clause fails because RSpec has overridden the method.

```
allow_any_instance_of(InternalService).to receive(:call).and_return(result)
expect_any_instance_of(InternalService).to receive(:call)
Foo.perform

=> Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
=> Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: call
```

How can I simply test that a method is being called on an object? Am I missing a bigger picture here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(InternalService).to receive(:call).and_call_original
Foo.perform
```

It's a `class` method, right? If not, replace the `expect` with `expect_any_instance_of`.

More about `and_call_original` can be found [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation).